# I have a problem with the my PHP file upload and getting less number of my data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin, web-development-server

I have echoed these scripts in my server:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('max_input_vars').'<br>';
echo ini_get('post_max_size');
?>
```

And got these result:

```
1000
500M
```

Will this cause any problem in my PHP file upload? I am  getting less number of my data like out of 870 data. I get only 143 from a PDF.

Comment: Could you paste full error message text ?

Comment: Just FYI, file uploads are controlled by `upload_max_filesize` directive. While `post_max_size` needs to be greater than, or at least equal to, `upload_max_filesize`, they both effect the allowed size of a file upload to php.